# How do we run a control command in ADF Lookup for KQL

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, kql, azure-data-explorer

I am planning to delete a ADX table content from Lookup in ADF using Kql before inserting into it.

So, In Lookup Query I tried running just table name to display the table content from ADX using `TableName` it works but to run a control command like `insert` or `clear` its showing error. The error says the query starts with a dot (`.`), eg. `.clear table log-table data`

```
Query: .
Request is invalid and cannot be processed: {
    "error": {
        "code": "Bad request",
        "message": "Control commands (starting with a dot '.') cannot be served from the query endpoint unless they are .show control commands.",
```

So, how do I solve it.

Comment: You can use [Azure data explorer command](https://i.imgur.com/lXqM6Y8.png) activity in ADF to execute the adx command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do we run a control command in ADF Lookup for KQL.

In lookup you can run only query, you cannot exceute adx command. In order to execute that in adf, use Azure data explorer command activity in ADF to execute the adx command.

[image]